# accessing MAT_DIALOG_DATA as value instead of reference in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, pass-by-value

When I am trying to access `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` variable its coming as ref. Ex:

```
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: any;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.temp = this.data;
}

update() {
this.temp= "abcd"; that. 
}
```

This is updating `this.data`. I want to update only `this.temp`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign `this.temp` to a new object

```
this.temp = {...this.data};
```

Comment: even after assigning like this. this.data is getting updated when I update this.temp.

Comment: Could you show the `html` of the dialog? Take a look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gn2fjf.

Answer (score 0):

If you want shallow copy, use `this.temp= Object.assign({}, this.data)`

For "deep" copy, use `this.temp= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data))`